# Impala has been in a state of Executing

Tags: impala

When I see the impala queries page, I found that there are a lot of has been showed that Executing the query, but the corresponding query is executed, whether the query is occupied memory, after the completion of hope everybody can help me have a look at

[image]

Answer (score 0):

using the search input on the top of this page. You can search whatever you like by inputting your conditions. Such as "query_duration>500s"

Here is the [API](http://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v10/path__clusters_-clusterName-_services_-serviceName-_impalaQueries.html) for you to get all the detail information about your job.

Have fun!